# How to build retaing wall for pool past 2ft?

Tags: pool, retaining-wall

All of these retaining wall blocks I see at big box hardware stores all say max build height 2ft. I have an area that requires closer to 2.5ft, a little more for base layer.. what are my options? Can I do something to stabilize to add another two layers or so?

This is to surround the dirt, as this area was dug out from slope. I will be back filling with river rock and a few inches of soil behind wall.

I was looking at these as I don't need a really fancy looking brick, but I need one that can go a little more than 2ft without breaking the bank:

[Brick](https://www.menards.com/main/building-materials/landscaping-materials/retaining-wall-block/crestone-beveled-retaining-wall-block/p-1444441414288.htm)

Comment: Not sure about the cost, but I much prefer the larger blocks that are pinned together. We have a retaining wall on the down hill side of our lot which is 28 inches above grade. It is of Keystone compact units (about 40 lb each) and has not moved in 25 years. I think an even better product is Versa-Lok. http://www.versa-lok.com/

Comment: I agree with Jim on having metal pins or rebar.